# How many connected components does this graph have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, equivalence-relations, graph-connectivity

**Let $G=(V,E)$ with $V = \{0,1,...,199\},$ $$E = \{(x,y) : x,y\in V, x \ne y, x \equiv y \pmod 7 \}$$
How many connected components does this Graph have?**

How can I answer this question? I have no idea how to solve this except draw a table in order to get the set $E$ and after that, write the graph, but I think there's a more straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Hint: the connected components of a graph that is defined by an equivalence relation are just the equivalence classes.

Comment: For example, the vertex set $\{4,11,18,25,32,39,46,...,186,193\}$ only connect with each other, not with any other vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 7. The components are $X_j; j=0,1,2,\ldots, 6$, where
$X_j = \{y; y \in \{0,1,2, \ldots, 199\}; y \pmod 7 = j\}$. Can you see why this is [and that each $X_j$ is nonempty].

If you need more hints, note that $G[X_j]$ is in fact a *clique*, for each $j \in \{0,1,2,\ldots 6\}$,
and that there are no edges between vertices in $X_j$ and $X_{j'}$ for
any two distinct $j,j' \in \{0,1,2,\ldots, 6\}$

Answer (score 1):

We can define an equivalence relation - $x\sim y\iff x\equiv y\pmod7$ (I leave it to the OP to check that this is indeed an equivalence relation).
So, $(x,y)\in E \iff x\equiv y\pmod 7\iff x\sim y\iff [x]=[y]$. So that means that two vertices connect iff they're in the same equivalence class. That means we have $7$ connected components - the same number of equivalence classes.